# Pandas substracting number of days from date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a new column "Starting_time" by subtracting 60 days out of "Harvest_date" but I get the same date each time. Can someone point out what did I do wrong please?

| Harvest_date |
| --- |
| 20.12.21 |
| 12.01.21 |
| 10.03.21 |

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta


df1 = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Flower_weight.csv')

def subtract_days_from_date(date, days):

    subtracted_date = pd.to_datetime(date) - timedelta(days=days)
    subtracted_date = subtracted_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    return subtracted_date

df1['Harvest_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.Harvest_date)
df1.style.format({"Harvest_date": lambda t: t.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")})

for harvest_date in df1['Harvest_date']:
    df1["Starting_date"]=subtract_days_from_date(harvest_date,60)

print(df1["Starting_date"])
```

| Starting_date |
| --- |
| 2021-10-05 |
| 2021-10-05 |
| 2021-10-05 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if the use of the loop was necessary here. Perhaps try the following:

```
df1_dates['Starting_date'] = df1_dates['Harvest_date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x) - timedelta(days=60))
df1_dates['Starting_date'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
df1_dates['Starting_date']
```

Comment: I was making the problem way too complex when the answer was so simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You're overwriting the series on each iteration of the last loop

```py
for harvest_date in df1['Harvest_date']:
    df1["Starting_date"]=subtract_days_from_date(harvest_date,60)
```

You can do away with the loop by vectorizing the `subtract_days_from_date` function.
You could also reference an index with `enumerate`

## [`np.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)

```py
import numpy as np


subtract_days_from_date = np.vectorize(subtract_days_from_date)

df1["Starting_date"]=subtract_days_from_date(df1["Harvest_date"], 60)
```

## [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```py
for idx, harvest_date in enumerate(df1['Harvest_date']):
    df1.iloc[idx][ "Starting_date"]=subtract_days_from_date(harvest_date,60)
```

Comment: I tried using both methos but I get the same error :TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: numpy.int32

Comment: I had to cast in my function subtracted_date = pd.to_datetime(date) - timedelta(days=int(days))  and now it works using np.vectorize. when I try enumerate it gives me another error: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Comment: @StetcoOana You're welcome! If it answers your Q please consider selecting it as the correct answer :)